# Alamofire: send parameter

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I want to post data as parameter like this:

```
{ 
    "data":
    [
        {
            "nik" : "lalaal"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I write to these parameters in Swift 3 using `Alamofire`?

i tried :

```
let parameter: Parameters = [
                "data":[[
                    "nik" : self.nik,
                    "check_type" : "IN",
                    "tanggal" : "01-08-2017 18:22:00",
                    "long" : String(locationList[projectChoosen].long!),
                    "lat" : String(locationList[projectChoosen].lat!),
                    "id_loc" : locationList[projectChoosen].id_project,
                    "id_project" : nil,
                    "nama_project" : locationList[projectChoosen].nama_project,
                    "barcode" : "",
                    "foto": "",
                    "mime_type" : "image/jpeg"

                    ]]
            ]
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Try this :  Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45437228/1242673

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
let dicRequest: NSDictionary = ["userid" : "test", "password" : "test123"]

let postParams:NSDictionary = [
    "data": dicRequest
]
let requestURL: String = String(format: "%@/Login", serverURL)
Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: postParams as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
    .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

    case .success(let JSON):
        print("response :-----> ",response)
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Dictionary object first in this formate

```
{ 
   "data":
   [
       {
           "nik" : "lalaal"
       }
   ]
}
```

After that you can convert this using NSJSONSerlisation to json string 
And than post using Almofire.

```
let array: [[String: String]] = [["nik": "lalaal"]]
let data =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let postParam: [String: String] = ["data": string]

let _ = Alamofire.request(apiType.url!, method: apiType.type!,parameters: postParam, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: nil).validate(statusCode: 200..<500).responseJSON { (response) in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample request using Alamofire and posting a dictionary as parameters:

```
let dataArray: [[String: String]] = [["nik": "lalaal"]]
let param: [String: [Any]] = ["data": dataArray]    
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
let dataIn: [String: String] = ["param1": "value1"]
let paramGo: [String: [String: String]] = ["data_title": dataIn]    
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: paramGo, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in }
```